# How to prevent pagebreak of a MultiCell in TCPDF

Tags: tcpdf

i have the following multicell in my pdf

```
$this->PDFinstance->MultiCell(($dimensions['wk'] / 2) - $dimensions['lm'], 0, 'my Text' . ' ' . '<br /><br /><img src="pathtoimg" />', 1, 'J', 0, 0, $dimensions['lm'], '', true, 0, true, true, 0);
```

The cell is at the end of the page-content.

If the cell is near/at pagebreak line, the content of cell cell will splited.

At the first page i see "my text" and at the second page i see the image.

How i can do it, that the cell complete moved to the second page, so how i can prevent to split the content of the cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long way of try and error, i find a way that works for me.

I put the compelete content in a seperat div and add `nobr="true"` to him.

After that the complete content will jump to the second page :-)